# html event bubbling for textbox

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I am using jQuery hotkey plugin to handle shortcut keys. Here I bind a <kbd>delete</kbd> key.

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'del', function (){ alert('hit
delete'); return false; });
```

The above snippet works when  delete button  is pressed in a document. There is a textbox in the page. When I press the delete button inside the textbox. alert box does not appear. Any idea why event does not bubbles up and alert message does not appear for text box.

Answer (score 1):

You must be stopping the event propagation inside `textbox` `keydown` event handler. It works fine take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cXFtN/

Comment: It works fine in fiddle. but it does not work in my page. just using the same snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the bind AFTER your textbox appears, cause when the textbox appears it is fresh new and doesn't know anything about your previous bind.